# Need help in explaining how we got a partial derivative

Tags: calculus

I do not really understand how did we get a partial derivative here:
[image]

where $$h_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta^Tx}}$$

I am confused on how to take this derivative with respect to one $\theta $ having entire expression defined with vector dot product $\theta^Tx$ in $h_{\theta}(x)$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\theta^Tx = \sum_k\theta_kx_k$ so that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\theta^T x = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\sum_k\theta_kx_k = x_j
$$

Therefore

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}h_\theta(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\theta^T x}} = \frac{e^{-\theta^Tx}}{(1 +e^{-\theta^Tx})^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\theta^Tx =  \frac{e^{-\theta^Tx}x_j}{(1 +e^{-\theta^Tx})^2}
$$

---

> **EDIT**
>
> As per request of the OP here are some more details

Consider the expression

$$
j(\theta) = y\log h_\theta(x) + (1 - y)\log(1 - h_\theta (x))
$$

where $x$ is in general a vector and $y$ an scalar, all of them independent of the variable $\theta$ (also a vector). We can take the derivative of the function $j(\theta) = j(\theta_1,\theta_2,\cdots)$ with respect to $\theta_j$, this is the result

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial j(\theta)}{\partial \theta_j} &=& \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_j}[y\log h_\theta(x) + (1 - y)\log(1 - h_\theta (x))] \\
&=& y \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_j}\log h_\theta(x) + (1 - y)\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_j}\log(1 - h_\theta (x))] \\
&=& \frac{y}{h_\theta(x)}\frac{\partial h_\theta(x)}{\partial \theta_j} + \frac{(1 - y)}{1 - h_\theta(x)}\frac{\partial (1-h_\theta(x))}{\partial \theta_j}  \\
&=& \left[ \frac{y}{h_\theta(x)} - \frac{(1 - y)}{1 - h_\theta(x)}\right]\frac{\partial h_\theta(x)}{\partial \theta_j} \\
&=& \left[ y(1 + e^{-\theta^Tx}) - (1 - y)(1 + e^{\theta^Tx})\right] \frac{x_je^{-\theta^Tx}}{(1 + e^{-\theta^Tx})} \\
&=& \left[ y  + \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\theta^T x}} - 1 \right] x_j \\
&=& (y + h_\theta(x) - 1)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Would not you mind to give me more details? On what rules you used to make differentiation.... I did not take calc to know all details, I know some basic rules. I also do not understand why y^i disappears,etc . I need help how to get from the entire expression to the given derivative

Comment: also why in denominator you have Theta x X instead of (- Theta x X), negative one. Actually the same question for denominator...

Comment: @YohanRoth I introduced more details, hope it helps now

Comment: Many many many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be based on the definition of the dot-product, $\theta^T x = \sum_{j=1}^d \theta_j x_j$, where $d$ is the number of physical dimensions of your problem, so 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \theta^T x = x_j.
$$
All further derivations are just the chain rule, e.g.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} h_\theta(x^{(i)}) = \frac{x_j^{(i)} e^{-\theta^T x^{(i)}}}{(1+e^{-\theta^T x^{(i)}})^2}
$$
from which your solution falls out with a bit of algebra.